# Swift Navigation Link problems

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I am having problems with `NavigationLink` in Swift and iOS 14. This is a known issue, however the problem solvers that I saw, are not sufficient. I found out that when a button with a `NavigationLink` is initialized early, it works and when you enter the page, you have the "go back" button. However, when the navigation link is in the middle, you are not able to go back when you enter the page and must close the app to go to the main screen again.

This is the code I am using:

```
HStack {
    Button(action: {
        if let url = URL(string: "I blacked this out to make no advert here") {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        }
    }){
        Text("Rate App").foregroundColor(.gray)
    }.modifier(navigationButtonViewStyle())
    
    Spacer()
    // this navigation link works fine
    NavigationLink(destination: HelpView()) {
        Text("FAQ").foregroundColor(.gray)
    }.modifier(navigationButtonViewStyle())
}.padding(.horizontal, 20)

VStack {
    Text("λSET")
    .font(.largeTitle)
    .fontWeight(.heavy)
    .bold()
    .padding(.top, 50)
    .onAppear(perform: prepareHaptics)
    .animation(.linear)
    
    Text("λudio System Engineer Tools")
    .fontWeight(.light)
    .animation(.linear(duration: 0.5))
    
    HStack {
        
        Spacer()
        
        // this navigation link is not showing the go back button when pressed and directed to the new screen
        NavigationLink(destination: AboutView()) {
            Text("About λSET")
            .fontWeight(.heavy)
            .bold()
        }
        
        
        Spacer()
        
    }.modifier(calcTitleViewStyle())
    .padding(.top, 20)
    .padding(.bottom, 60)
}
```

I am not sure what the problem is, but am curious what this could be. I am working on a workaround, but I would love to solve the problem at its roots.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself by explicitly setting the  .NavigationBar to true to force swift to load it. This was not needed in other pages, but I am now doing to make sure IOS14 accepts it, since a few things have been changed there.